# c# - How to set default values of custom controls for wpf designer?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I set default values for my custom wpf components?
I have a Textfield with the property "public Protection Protection{set;get;}". Protection is an enum:

```
public class Field3270Attributes{
    public enum Protection
    {
        PROTECTED,
        UNPROTECTED,
        AUTOSKIP
    }
}
```

The default value should be autoskip but protected is listed as the default value in the wpf designer since its the first element in the enum.
Setting the protection in the Textfield constructor did not help. 
I've tried DependencyProperty which does work but I have to specify a callback(setProtection) if I want any values except the default value to work.
If I dont specify a callback, changing values inside the wpf designer has no effect.
Is there a way to get the same behavior without having to specify callback methods for every property?

```
public class Textfield{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProtectionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Protection",
                                        typeof(Field3270Attributes.Protection),
                                        typeof(Textfield3270),
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Field3270Attributes.Protection.PROTECTED, setProtection));

    private static void setProtection(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Textfield field = (Textfield)sender;
        field.Protection = (Field3270Attributes.Protection)e.NewValue;
    }

    private Field3270Attributes.Protection protection;

    public Field3270Attributes.Protection Protection
    {
        get
        {
            return protection;
        }

        set
        {
            this.protection = value;

            if (value == Field3270Attributes.Protection.UNPROTECTED)
            {
                this.IsReadOnly = false;
                Background = Brushes.White;
            }
            else
            {
                this.IsReadOnly = true;
                Background = Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
            }
        }
    }

    public Textfield3270()
    {

        this.Protection = Field3270Attributes.Protection.PROTECTED;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `DependencyProperty` definition defines the default value. Change the first parameter in the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` from `PROTECTED` to `AUTOSKIP`

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ProtectionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Protection",
        typeof(Field3270Attributes.Protection),
        typeof(Textfield3270),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Field3270Attributes.Protection.AUTOSKIP, setProtection));
```

**EDIT**

You are overwriting your `Protection` `DependencyProperty` by implementing your own version with the same name. Remove your definition of the `Protection {get; set;}` completely.

If you want them to show up in the XAML designer, define the Get/Set as static methods like so:

```
public static Field3270Attributes.Protection GetProtection(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (Field3270Attributes.Protection)obj.GetValue(ProtectionProperty);
}

public static void SetProtection(DependencyObject obj, Field3270Attributes.Protection value)
{
    obj.SetValue(ProtectionProperty, value);
}
```

If you want to attach some logic on PropertyChanged, you can use this code in your class constructor:

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Textfield.ProtectionProperty, typeof(Textfield));
if (dpd != null) dpd.AddValueChanged(this, delegate { Protection_Changed(); });
```

And your changed method would look like this:

```
private void Protection_Changed()
{
    Field3270Attributes.Protection protection = GetProtection(this);

    // Do something with value
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that was just an error in my description. I had it at autoskip before and changed to protected but the problem is, how can I set the default value and ensure, that changes from the default value to any other value in the wpf designer are recognized? Without the callback, I can change the values and nothing happens but I don't want to define callbacks for every single value.

Comment: When you register a DependencyProperty, a Get/Set is automatically created for that property. You seem to be overwritting the default `TextField.Protection` that points to the DependencyProperty, and implementing your own version of the property. Try removing your version of the `Protection` property and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, I am overwriting the get/set of the Protection property, as you can see in the code above. I changed that to an auto implemented property now:

    public Field3270Attributes.Protection Protection { set; get; }

But that does not work either, I still need the callback, even though it only sets the fields property.

Comment: @Markus See my edit. The `public Field3270Attributes.Protection Protection { set; get; }` is still overwriting the `DependencyProperty` Protection.